# Installing leksah from source

Tags: haskell, cabal

I tried to install leksah via cabal but I got tons of different build errors so I tried to build it from git.

I followed this guide http://www.leksah.org/download.html and I was able to build binary-shared,ltk and leksah-server but when I try to build leksah I get

```
[maik@maik leksah]$ cabal install 
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: leksah-0.13.2.5
trying: leksah-0.13.2.5:+webkit
trying: leksah-0.13.2.5:+gtk3
```

It does not give me a clear error message, any ideas what I can do?

Comment: It's worth noting that because the language is so terse and well-designed most haskellers actually don't use IDEs (which Leksah claims to be) - the text editors are preferred. I've been using SumlimeText + SublimeHaskell for quite some time now and am pretty much satisfied. The only thing that's missing is refactoring capabilities, but don't expect that from Leksah either.

Comment: I have updated the instructions in the development section on http://leksah.org/download.html

Comment: Make sure your ghc version is 7.8.3 and above.